# Flask SQLAlchemy, cannot get it to create tables, but it does create the database file

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this same problem in two of the Flask web apps I am working on creating. I can create the database and database file, but the models are not creating tables.

extensions.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask import g, current_app

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

models.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask import g, current_app

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

from .config import Config
from .extensions import bcrypt, db


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static")

    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    # login_manager.init_app(app) # waiting to make userloader

    
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        db.session.commit()

    from concorn.main.routes import main
    app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix="/")

    from concorn.contractors.routes import contractor
    app.register_blueprint(contractor, url_prefix="/contractor")

    from concorn.sub_contractors.routes import sub_contractor
    app.register_blueprint(sub_contractor, url_prefix="/sub-contractor")

    return app
```

conconrn/main/routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from ..extensions import db
from ..models import ContactInformation

main = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@main.route("/")
def index():
    contact = ContactInformation("Smokier", "Lemur", "4569878794", "test@gmail.com")
    with current_app.app_context():
        db.session.add(contact)
        db.session.commit()
    elements = {'title': "concorn", "company": "Contractor Link LLC"}
    return render_template('index.html', elements=elements)
```

This is my first time coming back to working with Flask and I believe I have everything set up to be close to the standard. When I try to insert into the ContactInformation obj it says the table "contact_information" doesn't exist. I then went and tried to go through and set the table name to "contact_information" manually and still it doesn't exist.

Comment: Move `db.create_all()` to the end of your function (after the blueprint imports). Failing that, you'll need to explicitly import the models so it can see them